# Getting number of rows in a sql server table using php

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying get the number of rows (or number of primary keys) in a table using PHP and then outputting the result in to a webpage. I am new to SQL server and this wouldn't give me any results

```
//code above omitted and connected to the database
$query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ElectronicShop";
$data_count = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $query_count) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));
//$row_count = sqlsrv_fetch_row($data_count);
echo "<br>ROW COUNT:".sqlsrv_fetch_object($data_count)."<br>";
```

Comment: Perhaps RTFMing would help: http://php.net/sqlsrv_fetch_object. You're fetching an OBJECT representing a row of results from your query, not the actual value of the count you did. Since you're fetching an object, your echo is trying to output that object, and will fail since whatever class that object is, it won't have a toString()-type auto method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
//code above omitted and connected to the database
$query_count = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS myCounter FROM ElectronicShop";
$data_count = sqlsrv_query($connectString, $query_count) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(SQLSRV_ERR_ALL), true));
//$row_count = sqlsrv_fetch_row($data_count);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($data_count);
echo "<br>ROW COUNT:".$row->myCounter."<br>";
```

From the doc: https://php.net/sqlsrv-fetch-object