# How to count rows in a database

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

How do I count the rows in a database using PHP?

For example I have database called `DB` and a table inside called `members`. Inside the `members` table I want to count all rows to make a site statistics total number of `members`.

I use

```
$Profile = $core_db->Execute("Select ID, Name, Age, Nationality, Age from Profiles where Name='NAME'");
```

So I'm trying to count the number of names here.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting number of rows in a sql server table using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867705/getting-number-of-rows-in-a-sql-server-table-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$core_db->Execute("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Profiles WHERE Name='NAME'")`.

Welcome to stack overflow, just a gentle reminder. You can always try to google first before posting your question here.

Comment: Be careful what you assume, `COUNT(ID)` might work in this situation but understand the difference between that and `COUNT(*)`